# PHP is loading, but not sending the email to me

Tags: php, email

I will admit that I am not the best at PHP, but what I am doing usually works well enough for me because the clients just need the information sent to their emails, and the security question works well enough to keep spam away from their inbox. But for some reason, this code will not work and I cannot figure out why. This same code with different variables is on another site I have and is tested and working. Does anyone have any advice?

```
<form action="submit_form.php" method="POST" >
<p>Name<br /><input type="text" name="name" required /></p>
<p>Email Address<br /><input type="text" name="email" required /></p>
<p>Phone Number<br /><input type="text" name="phone" required /></p>
<p>County<br /><input type="text" name="county" required /></p>
<p>Annual Income<br /><input type="text" name="income" required /></p>
<p>What is 4 + 1? (anti-spam)<br /><input type="text" name="answer" required /></p>
<input type="submit" value="Take The First Step" />
</form>

<?php # BOOST
$name = $_POST['name'];
$email = $_POST['email'];
$phone = $_POST['phone'];
$county = $_POST['county'];
$income = $_POST['income'];
$correct_answer = '5';
$answer = $_POST['answer'];

if ($correct_answer != $answer) {

die("You're not a valid user of this site!");

}
else {


$to = "glenn@boostbizseo.com";
$subject = "USDA LOANS";
$message = "USDA LOANS:\n
Name: $name
Email: $email
Phone: $phone
County: $county
Annual Income: $income";
$from = "USDA Loans";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
echo "Thank you for getting in contact with us. We will be in contact with you soon          regarding your USDA Loan! <a href=http://www.usdaloansmo.com>Click Here</a> to go back to our website!";
}
?>
```

Comment: As a note, you're missing your opening PHP tag. `?php` should be `<?php`

Comment: I fixed it on here, but that was just an error in copying from my document. Thank you

Comment: You need to do some basic debugging yourself? Check `mail()`'s return value for a boolean false (failure). Check your mail server's logs to see if PHP even handed over the email properly, and what happened to it afterwards.

Comment: @serupticious: domain names with 'seo' and 'biz' in them? Nothing is EVER suspect about those... biziness people are ALWAYS totally 100% respectable and legit...

Comment: I work for the company Boost Web+SEO. Our URL is boostbizseo.com. That is my email address. My client's email address will be added when I figure out this problem.

Comment: You need to specify from correctly secondly you need to test your code on your server with email server configured properly.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
    $from = "someonelse@example.com"; //email ID
    $headers = "From:" . $from;


    mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

I believe this will work.

Answer (score 0):

This is wrong:

```
$from = "USDA Loans";
mail($to,$subject,$message,$headers);
```

You don't use `$from` and `$headers` is undefined.

Comment: could you tell me what to do to fix the problem? I don't mean to sound ignorant, but I do not know much php at all which is why everything is so basic.

Comment: @user2697116 Check the manual on `mail`: http://php.net/manual/en/function.mail.php

Answer (score 0):

Here is how you send email using php.

```
$to="some@domain.com";
$subject="Your subject";
$header="from: ABCName <me@mydomain.com>";
$message="Message \r\n";
$sentmail = mail($to,$subject,$message,$header);
if($sentmail)
{
    echo "Done";
}
else
{
    echo "Oops, Something went wrong";
}
```